# How to configure dhcpcd to work with default dns?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, dns, dhcp

I have an embedded Linux device which connects to wifi. It is configured with DHCP and configured to use a specific DNS server. The current configuration works.

However, I want to remove the DNS configuration and let DHCP give me an automatic DNS (this can be done along with IP response as far as I understand).
When I remove the nameserver from `/etc/resolv.conf` I am able to ping but name resolution does not work.

```
nslookup: write to '127.0.0.1': Connection refused
```

I'm probably missing some configuration. Can anyone help?
I'm using `wpa_supplicant` and `dhcpcd` (we are not running network-manager/bind etc).
Do I need additional daemon or is this just a configuration issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DNS server address *has to be* written to the `/etc/resolv.conf` file. That's where programs expect to find it – there is no other standard place that dhcpcd would store the DHCP-provided server addresses; all DHCP clients need to update the resolv.conf file.

(If your /etc is read-only, the file can be a symlink to somewhere in /run or /tmp.)

dhcpcd will automatically update /etc/resolv.conf using the `dhcpcd-hooks/20-resolv.conf` hook script that comes as part of a standard dhcpcd installation. Make sure this script and the general `dhcpcd-run-hooks` script are present in your embedded system.

(On my system these scripts are at `/usr/lib/dhcpcd`, but the path might vary depending on compile options.)

Comment: brilliant! it works-thanks!. I should have read more carefully the hooks section..

Comment: Tried on a RPi4. dhcpcd concatenates `/etc/resolv.conf.head` and `/etc/resolv.conf.tail` files respectively before and after its own configuration. So, if one needs a default nameserver, should put it in head file. If an override is needed, should be put in the tail file.

Comment: @cbugk: If an override is needed, put `static dns_servers=` in the DHCP client's own configuration... Keep in mind that the resolv.conf nameservers are not necessarily read in order; older glibc versions will use the first, while newer ones will choose a server at random. (Concatenation is done by `resolvconf` – dhcpcd runs resolvconf (which may be either Openresolv or Debian's own resolvconf) with DNS obtained from each interface, which then combines all data + head/tail files into the final resolv.conf file.)

Comment: Frankly I was following this repo https://github.com/newracom/nrc7394_sw_pkg/releases for some fancy wireless card. They have their own template file manupilated depending on the configuration, so I did not want to edit just yet. So head/tail files were a quick workaround. In general though, what you mentioned is the way.